# Do you have any way to update 'RubyGem' for aptana studio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configure, aptana

I have installed the Aptana studio (Aptana RadRails Version: 2.0.5.1278709071-7k7W97FDk_sBcJt_Y-tkCz0V4CXB).

When I create a Rails Project I have the following error:

> Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (you have 1.3.1).
>   
> Please `gem update --system` and try again.

I had the same error when I try to do run the project. When I try execute from console the command `gem update --system` I had the error:

> rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7

Do you have any way to update 'RubyGem' for Aptana Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. For windows 7.

1. Go to and open the view Windows -> Show View -> RubyGems
2. On the new view opened you should view an options tool sets, move over this and execute the 'Update All Gems', while executing the operation, is possible see some message errors.
3. The server should be could execute.

That's works for me .... :)